# Authorize Azure Requests using Bearer toke?

Tags: azure, computer-vision, ocr

Is it possible to send a request to Microsoft Azure OCR using authorization token instead of Subscription-Key? I searched a lot on the internet but found nothing and thus I would be thankful If you can help.

Comment: What kind of request/operation that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you talking about the `computer vision` (Azure cognitive service) ? You can check this document to authenticate using Azure AD: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/authentication?tabs=powershell#authenticate-with-azure-active-directory

Comment: I want to send OCR requests on the client side using Bearer Token.

Comment: I want to make an app with a feature that enables a user to send an image and recognize the text in the image. It is easy to do it using Subscription-Key for verification of the request but I think it will be a big problem as the user would be able to find and use my subscription-key. And as it is mentioned here, authToken cannot be used with computer vision https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/authentication?tabs=powershell#authenticate-with-an-authentication-token . Is there any solution for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can follow this workflow:

1. users send a request to your App for an access token.
2. Your app checks the user's permission(you should implement the procedure yourself), if vailed, your app uses a subscription key to get an access token for the user by [Authenticate with Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/authentication?tabs=powershell#authenticate-with-azure-active-directory) and
   reply this token to the user.
3. Users use this token to call the OCR service from client-side.

As the doc indicated, you should create a new service principal in your Azure AD, and go to Azure Portal=>your Azure cognitive service => Access control to add a cognitive service user role to the new created SP:

[image]

So that it could request an access token for this service from Azure AD by request below:

[image]

By using this access token, we will be able to call vision ocr service:

[image]

Endpoint in this case:

[image]

Comment: Yes I am doing it for the translator and speech services and it works properly, but it does not work for the vision api which might be due to the fact that Azure does not yet support Access token for vision api as mention in their documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/authentication?tabs=powershell#authenticate-with-an-authentication-token. Could you please explain yourself with an example?

Comment: @ZyadOmer999, my apologies, I did not noticed this way does not work for vision API, I have updated my answer by using an access token from Azure AD.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Stanley. But could you please tell what is that "stancogtest" in the url? And where should I specify the region? I am asking about that because I get this error "Unauthorized. Access token is missing, invalid, audience is incorrect (https://cognitiveservices.azure.com), or have expired."

Comment: @ZyadOmer999, my pleasure :） "stancogtest" is my cognitive service name, you can find the endpoint in your cognitive service instance overview(I have appended the capture in my answer). In this case, you should use this endpoint and there is no need to specify the region.

Comment: Everything is clear. Thank you very much, you are really helpful. One more question please, I want to know if it is possible for someone to get the endpoint in the token if he converts it to human readable format like www.jwt.io

Comment: @ZyadOmer999, I am afraid it is not possible. `scope` is fixed to be `https://cognitiveservices.azure.com/.default`  while we get tokens, so that `aud` claim is fixed in the access token, we can't change it